# Create array pointer in protobuf using go lang

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am new to grpc, I have created proto file with service called Accounts,have method name GetValidators,I want to create silce pointer []* to BondedValidators and UnbondingValidators variable inside the message which is using (gogoproto.customtype).

```
syntax = 'proto3';
package grpc;

import "github.com/gogo/protobuf/gogoproto/gogo.proto";
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

option (gogoproto.marshaler_all) = false;
option (gogoproto.unmarshaler_all) = false;
option (gogoproto.sizer_all) = false;
option (gogoproto.goproto_registration) = true;
option (gogoproto.messagename_all) = true;
option (gogoproto.protosizer_all) =false;

service Accounts {
rpc GetValidators(Empty) returns (ValidatorOutput);
}

message ValidatorOutput {
uint64 BlockHeight  = 1 ;       
repeated google.protobuf.ListValue  BondedValidators  = 2   [(gogoproto.customtype) = "github.com/gallactic/gallactic/core/validator.Validator", (gogoproto.nullable) = false];
repeated google.protobuf.ListValue  UnbondingValidators  = 3 [(gogoproto.customtype) = "github.com/gallactic/gallactic/core/validator.Validator", (gogoproto.nullable) = false];
}
```

whenever below code is used  :

```
protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. -I$GOPATH/src-I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpcecosystem/grpc-gateway/third_party/googleapis --gofast_out=plugins=grpc:./ ./protobuf/account.proto
```

Its generate output in .pb.go file, with three extra variable

```
type ValidatorOutput struct {
BlockHeight          uint64                        `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=BlockHeight,proto3" json:"BlockHeight,omitempty"`
BondedValidators     []github_com_gallactic_gallactic_core_validator.Validator `protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=BondedValidators,customtype=github.com/gallactic/gallactic/core/validator.Validator" json:"BondedValidators"`
UnbondingValidators  []github_com_gallactic_gallactic_core_validator.Validator `protobuf:"bytes,3,rep,name=UnbondingValidators,customtype=github.com/gallactic/gallactic/core/validator.Validator" json:"UnbondingValidators"`
XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral struct{}                                                   `json:"-"`
XXX_unrecognized     []byte                                                     `json:"-"`
XXX_sizecache        int32                                                      `json:"-"`
 }
```

output should be

```
type ValidatorOutput struct {
BlockHeight          uint64                                                     `protobuf:"varint,1,opt,name=BlockHeight,proto3" json:"BlockHeight,omitempty"`
BondedValidators     []*github_com_gallactic_gallactic_core_validator.Validator `protobuf:"bytes,2,rep,name=BondedValidators,customtype=github.com/gallactic/gallactic/core/validator.Validator" json:"BondedValidators"`
UnbondingValidators  []*github_com_gallactic_gallactic_core_validator.Validator `protobuf:"bytes,3,rep,name=UnbondingValidators,customtype=github.com/gallactic/gallactic/core/validator.Validator" json:"UnbondingValidators"`
}
```

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50704319/xxx-type-in-generated-pb-go-file

Answer (score 1):

gogo proto will remove the pointers when you use the `nullable=false` option, so you'll need to remove the `(gogoproto.nullable) = false` options from the proto definition to have it generate []*foo

Comment: i remove the "(gogoproto.nullable) = false" still same, its generating BondedValidators     []github_com_gallactic_gallactic_core_validator.Validator

Comment: In this [conversation](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf/issues/421#issuecomment-402633940) you can find the reason why `gogoproto.nullable` option don't work in `proto3` syntax.